# Rails API - Expecting json showing created object. Getting 302 status code with no object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rails-api

I have 2 apps. A **plain Ruby app** and a **Rails app** that listens for POSTS from the plain Ruby app and also shows data that has been posted.

I am trying to design a basic API for my Rails app. I use Faraday to `POST` some `JSON` to my app. That part is working as **I can see objects are being created after the `POST`**.

In my `resp` I am expecting to see something related to the object I just created. Instead I do see a `status=302`.

How can I get a response back that shows `success` and maybe some json with the created object would be nice. Really I just want an indicator that the `POST` went correctly.

--- code from **plain Ruby app** that POSTS to my **Rails app**

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tests') do |faraday|
  faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
  faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
  faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
end   

resp = conn.post do |req|
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = data.to_json
end
```

**When I examine `resp` in pry I get this**

`[1] pry(#<Object>)> resp
=> #<Faraday::Response:0x007fb8c3a317d0
 @env=
  #<struct Faraday::Env
   method=:post,
   body="<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://localhost:3000/tests/2\">redirected</a>.</body></html>",
   url=#<URI::HTTP:0x007fb8c34176b0 URL:http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tests>,
   request=
    #<struct Faraday::RequestOptions
     params_encoder=nil,
     proxy=nil,
     bind=nil,
     timeout=nil,
     open_timeout=nil,
     boundary=nil,
     oauth=nil>,
   request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.1", "Content-Type"=>"application/json"},
   ssl=
    #<struct Faraday::SSLOptions
     verify=nil,
     ca_file=nil,
     ca_path=nil,
     verify_mode=nil,
     cert_store=nil,
     client_cert=nil,
     client_key=nil,
     certificate=nil,
     private_key=nil,
     verify_depth=nil,
     version=nil>,
   parallel_manager=nil,
   params=nil,
   response=nil,
   response_headers=
    {"x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN",
     "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block",
     "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff",
     "location"=>"http://localhost:3000/tests/2",
     "content-type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8",
     "cache-control"=>"no-cache",
     "x-request-id"=>"62da5fdc-6f00-4f2a-9c93-c80f6e08c4f8",
     "x-runtime"=>"0.219049",
     "server"=>"WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.0/2014-12-25)",
     "date"=>"Thu, 30 Jul 2015 16:54:07 GMT",
     "content-length"=>"95",
     "connection"=>"close",
     "set-cookie"=>
      "request_method=POST; path=/, _cimportal_session=QjdTN0lOaXBMSTZYT0hvOCsyOVozeW43VTRiSHZXTTBlakJFMmllTTNmdTYvbnd5QllWZnRnSDJhN2lHSDJxM3phSHZWU1VGcElSWEY0V0N3dXd6RHdzTW5leHFtY3hoNDNaTHRCZ2l3ODVaZTVIcXc0eDBnMHdKelhhN2lZeEdIYXNlWU9ZaThETkUvYnRTL293c0lKRGU1N3FrY2liN2t6anBCNlJMaXJFPS0tZmhIQmN0VXVvVEJ4VE5rQ3JLdWphZz09--965190ef9f588d95347f2ee25044eb79f3b5d289; path=/; HttpOnly"},
   status=302>,
 @on_complete_callbacks=[]>`

As you can see there is a status=302 at the bottom. How can I get a `success` here along with some json representing the object?

**Here is the main part of the Rails `create` method**

```
@test = Test.new(test_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @test.save
    format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @test }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

What am I missing? The `POST` is working but I would like to see a response that it is successful.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding ".json" to the URL so the controller won't think the request is a regular HTML request.

If that fixes the problem, then you can either add that to all of your URL's or configure the controller to `respond_to :json` (and remove the `format.html` lines from the controller).

I typically do this in the application controller so all controller methods will inherit it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  respond_to :json

end
```

You can also do some stuff in your routes to lock this down further, but my memory is a little foggy on this:

```
resources :users, defaults: { format: :json }
```

**EDIT**

Above I suggested remove the `format.html` lines, but really you can remove all of that format stuff and just let the method return some JSON without caring what the format is:

```
if @test.save
  # assuming there is a jBuilder view for this and that you have the
  # respond_to :json in the controller or application controller
  render :show, status: :created, location: @test
else 
  render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a line that says:

```
format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @test }
```

This is causing the 302 you're seeing.

Instead try something like

```
format.json { render status: :created, json: @test }
```

This should return a 201 status code and respond with the JSON of the new object created.

Comment: Notice that it's rendering a status of "created" which is a 200 level HTTP response. A redirect response is in the 300 range. I don't think this will fix the problem, because it's not the thing that is causing the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I used both answers to help. Mainly I added .json to the end of the URL and it pretty much started to work. I also changed to this `format.json { render status: :created, json: @test }`